# Rendering Values in a Step Function: extract YYYY-MM from 2022-10-20

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to get a date prefix from a date in an AWS Step Function. When I try to call a variable from a previous step, that variable doesn't render. Here is the step function code:

```json
    {
      "Comment": "Set and use a new variable in Step Functions",
      "StartAt": "Set Date Prefix",
      "States": {
        "Set Date Prefix": {
          "Type": "Pass",
          "Result": {
            "date_prefix": "${$$.Execution.Input.date.substr(0,7)}"
          },
          "ResultPath": "$.date_prefix",
          "Next": "Use Date Prefix"
        },
        "Use Date Prefix": {
          "Type": "Pass",
          "Result": {
            "date_prefix_used": "$.date_prefix"
          },
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
```

When I pass the following input:

```json
    {
      "date": "2022-10-20"
    }
```

I get the following as output:

```json
    {
      "date_prefix_used": "$.date_prefix"
    }
```

when I should have gotten:

```json
    {
    "date_prefix": "2022-10",
    "date_prefix_used": "2022-10"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect your "Set Date Prefix" task is not returning the expected result either.

Answer (score 0):

You can intinsically extract the `YYYY-MM` from a date string input like `2022-10-20` with two Pass states.  A Pass state can apply substitutions and State Machine [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html), but in the `Parameters` field, not the `Result` field.  Remember the `.$` suffix on keys whose values have substitutions.  Otherwise, the values will be treated as literals.

```json
{
  "Comment": "Set and use a new variable in Step Functions",
  "StartAt": "SplitDate",
  "States": {
    "SplitDate": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "date_components.$": "States.StringSplit($.date, '-')"
      },
      "Next": "GetPrefix"
    },
    "GetPrefix": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "InputPath": "$.date_components",
      "Parameters": {
        "date_prefix.$": "States.Format('{}-{}',States.ArrayGetItem($, 0), States.ArrayGetItem($, 1))"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

The `Split Date` task splits the date with `States.StringSplit`.

```json
{
  "date_components": [ "2022", "10", "20" ]
}
```

The `GetPrefix` task reassembles the the year and month with `States.Format` and `States.ArrayGetItem`:

```json
{
  "date_prefix": "2022-10"
}
```